# Firebase Dynamic Links not shortening URL

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to get Dynamic Links to shorten my URL with the following code:

```
guard let link = URL(string: "https://myapp.com") else { return }
let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "https://app.myapp.com/link"
let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix)
linkBuilder?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "com.myapp.ios")

guard let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder?.url else { return }
print("The long URL is: \(longDynamicLink)")

let options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
options.pathLength = .short
linkBuilder?.options = options
linkBuilder?.shorten() { url, warnings, error in
  guard let url = url, error != nil else { return }
  print("The short URL is: \(url)")
}
```

It's printing the long URL fine, but the line below (for short URL) is never being called:

```
print("The short URL is: \(url)")
```

Because `url` returns nil and I have no idea why. Nothing I've found in the guides or online has lead me in the right direction.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Bumping this since it's been a while

Comment: Bumping this again.

Comment: Bumping this one more time.

Comment: Once again bumping this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the following is incorrect:

```
guard let url = url, error != nil else { return }
```

You are saying make sure there is a non nil URL and make sure there is an error.

I think the Firebase docs are wrong. Instead, you want:

```
guard let url = url, error == nil else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done here :

```
linkBuilder?.shorten() { url, warnings, error in
  guard let url = url, error != nil else { return }
  print("The short URL is: \(url)")
}
```

is you are unwrapping the url and checking if error contains some Error, then you are printing **'The short URL is: (url)'** it means if **shorten()** succeeds and there's no Error your print method will never be executed.

What you have to do is, First check if error doesn't contain any Error than call print()

```
linkBuilder?.shorten() { url, warnings, error in
  guard error == nil else { return }
  if let shortUrl = url {
      print("The short url is \(shortUrl)")
  }
}
```